# Equating iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I'm facing some problems with set::iterators in c++. I have a set of 2-D points and I need to iterate and compare these points three by three.

My thought was to use three loops incrementing the iterators, one by one. But c++ gave me an error when I tried:

```
for (set<pair<double, double> >::iterator i = S.begin(); i != S.end(); i++){
    for (set<pair<double, double> >::iterator j = i+1; j != S.end(); j++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Edit: the error was "error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘i + 1’"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::set has a bidirectional iterator. It has no such operation as iterator + integer number. So use instead

```
for (set<pair<double, double> >::iterator j = std::next( i ); j != S.end(); j++){
```

Comment: Note that `std::next()` is a C++11 feature. But you can also get it from Boost if you're not up to C++11 yet.

Comment: @FredLarson or write your own `next`: `template<typename I, typename D> I next(I in, D n=1){std::advance(in, n); return in;}`